# How to super impose two elements and still have responsive behavior with zurb foundation

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

I need to put a `<canvas>` element on the top of a `<video>` element in order to draw something on my video. I can do this by setting the position of theses two elements to "absolute" but I lose the responsive behavior. With foundation is it possible to make these two elements seen as one and move the same way when the DOM layout changes, for example when resizing the window ?

Answer (score 0):

Normally the parent element of the  and the  needs to have position: relative in order for their absolute positioning to be calculated relative to their parent rather than relative to the page.